# Count для пользовательского класса строки MyString - C++

Tags: c++

Хочу реализовать поиск существующих элементов вектора,но столкнулся с проблемой

Вот такая ошибка в main на этой строке

```
if (det_name.count(f1))
```

Вот такую ошибку выдает

> 'class std::vector' has no member named 'count'

Я понимаю в чем ошибка,но как написать count для MyString не знаю.
Подскажите пожалуйста,как мне это сделать?

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyString
{
public:

void set_len(int len)
    {
        length=len;
    }

int get_len()
    {
        return length;
    }   
//конструктор без параметров
MyString()
{
str = nullptr;
length = 0;
}

//конструктор с параметрами, при создании объекта класса необходимо перелать строку которую он будет хранить
MyString(const char *str)
{

length = strlen(str);// функция strlen получает количество символов в строке которую мы передаём в объект

// выделяем память для динамического массива где будет храниться наша строка 
// +1 символ так как нужно место в массиве под терминирующий 0
this->str = new char[length + 1];

// копируем символы строки в массив нашего класса
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
this->str[i] = str[i];
}

//закрываем строку терминирующим нулём
this->str[length] = '\0';

}
// деструктор, отвечает за освобождение ресурвов занятых объектом, вызывается при уничтожении объекта класса
~MyString()
{
delete[] this->str;
}

// конструктор копировании, необходим для создании точной копи объекта класса но в другой области памяти
MyString(const MyString &other)
{
length = strlen(other.str);
this->str = new char[length + 1];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
this->str[i] = other.str[i];
}

this->str[length] = '\0';
}

// перегруженый оператор присваивания, вызывается когда необходимо присвоить значение одного объекта другому
MyString& operator =(const MyString &other)
{
// здесь логика похожа на ту которая реализована в конструкторе, за исключением того, что нам нужно позаботиться
// об освобождении ресурсов объекта если до копирования в него новой строки он уже содержал код 
//+ страндартный синтаксис перегрузки оператора =
if (this->str != nullptr)
{
delete[] str;
}

length = strlen(other.str);
this->str = new char[length + 1];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
this->str[i] = other.str[i];
}

this->str[length] = '\0';

return *this;

}

//перегруженный оператор сложения, в текущей реализации класса String необходим для конкатенации строк
MyString operator+(const MyString &other)
{
//создаём новый пустой объект где будим хранить результат конкатенации строк и который будет результатом работы
// перегруженного оператора +
MyString newStr;
// получаем количество символов в обеих строках для конкатенации

int thisLength = strlen(this->str);
int otherLength = strlen(other.str);

newStr.length = thisLength + otherLength;

// выделяем место в динамической памяти под новую строку
newStr.str = new char[thisLength + otherLength + 1];

//копируем данные из 2х конкатенируемых строк в новую строку
int i = 0;
for (; i < thisLength; i++)
{
newStr.str[i] = this->str[i];
}

for (int j = 0; j < otherLength; j++, i++)
{
newStr.str[i] = other.str[j];
}

newStr.str[thisLength + otherLength] = '\0';

// возвращаем результат конкатенации
return newStr;
}

// выводит строку в консоль, в идеале для этого необходима перегрузка оператора «
void Print()
{
cout << str;
}

int Length()
{
return length;
}

bool operator ==(const MyString & other)
{
if (this->length != other.length)
{
return false;
}


for (int i = 0; i < this->length; i++)
{
if (this->str[i] != other.str[i])
{
return false;
}
}
return true;
}

bool operator !=(const MyString & other) 
{
return !(this->operator==(other));
}

char& operator [](int index) 
{
return this->str[index];
}

MyString(MyString &&other) 
{ 
this->length = other.length; 
this->str = other.str; 
other.str = nullptr; 
} 

friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, MyString& t);
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const MyString& t);
void get_input (std::istream& in);

int length; 
private: 
// Указатель на массив char, хранит символы, которые мы передали в наш объект. 
char *str; 
}; 


void MyString::get_input (std::istream& in)
{
    while (true)
    {
        char c = in.get ();

        if (c == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }

        if (length == 0)
        {
            length = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            ++length;
        }

        char* newStr = new char[length];
        if (str != NULL)
        {
            strcpy (newStr, str);
        }
        newStr[length-2] = c;
        newStr[length-1] = '\0';

        delete[] str;

        str = newStr;
    }
}

bool operator == (char, const MyString&)
{
    return false;
}

std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, MyString& t)
{
    t.get_input (in);
    return in;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const MyString& t)
{
    out << t.str;
    return out;
}

int main()
{
MyString f1;
    MyString f2;

    cout<<"Список названий существующих деталей: "<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    copy( det_name.begin(), det_name.end(), ostream_iterator<MyString>(cout, "\n"));
    cout<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"Введите первый существующий элемент:  ";
    cin>>f1;
    do{

    if (det_name.count(f1)) 
    {
   cout<<"Элемент найден"<<endl;
    } 
else 
    {
   cout<<endl;
   cout<<"\aЭлемент не найден"<<endl;
   cout<<"Введите существующий элемент:  ";
   cin>>f1;

    }
}while(!(det_name.count(f1)));

    cout<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"Введите второй существующий элемент:  ";
    cin>>f2;

        do{

    if (det_name.count(f2)) 
    {
   cout<<"Элемент найден"<<endl;
    } 
else 
    {
   cout<<endl;
   cout<<"\aЭлемент не найден"<<endl;
   cout<<"Введите существующий элемент:  ";
   cin>>f2;

    }
}while(!(det_name.count(f2)));

    cout<<endl<<endl;

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Для этого есть стандартный алгоритм `std::count`.

Comment: С типом данных int работает на ура,но с пользовательским ,что-то нет.

Comment: Для этого свой тип надо доработать, чтобы он соответствовал требованиям алгоритма.

Comment: не можете помочь этом?